# `byobu` window with `sudo su -`

Tags: sudo, byobu, tmux

I'm aware that what I would like to do is not safe...

I would like to open a window in my byobu session with the root prompt. (i.e. with `sudo su -`.) Once I get the root prompt, I would like to execute my script (as root) and then give me the root prompt again.

I can achieve the first part by putting the following line in my `window.tmux`:

```
new-window -n 'root' sudo su -;
```

I tried to `send-keys` to the window (thanks to [@user5325](https://askubuntu.com/users/696268/user5325) for the corrections), I get the root prompt. However it is not executing the command.

```
new-window -n root sudo su -;
send-keys mypassword C-m;
send-keys source ~/command.sh C-m;
```

**NOTE:** For some reasons it is not possible to use `visudo` on these commands.

Comment: Remove the quotes `'` from the `send-keys` commands. Also you MUST end the command with a semi-colon `;`.